# Checkbox listview

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox

I have a listview1 with a checkbox on each row, I want to pass the checked items to a listview2 when checked.

```
            private void Listview1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem Item in listView1.Items)
        {
            if (Item != null)
            {
                ListViewItem li;
                if (Item.Checked == true)
                {
                    li = listView2.Items.Add(listView2.Items[0].ToString());
                    li.SubItems.Add(listView2.Items[1].ToString());
                    li.SubItems.Add(listView2.Items[2].ToString());
                    li.SubItems.Add(listView2.Items[3].ToString());
                    li.SubItems.Add(listView2.Items[4].ToString());
                    li.SubItems.Add(listView2.Items[5].ToString());
                    li.SubItems.Add(listView2.Items[6].ToString());
                    li.SubItems.Add(listView2.Items[7].ToString());
                    li.SubItems.Add(listView2.Items[8].ToString());
                    li.SubItems.Add(listView2.Items[9].ToString());

                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: what is the problem you facing in this?

Comment: The items are not passing over to the listview2 when checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the `Clone()` method, this will add all the same checked items from `listView1` to `listView2`:

```
foreach (ListViewItem Item in listView1.Items) {
   if (Item.Checked) {
        listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)Item.Clone());
   } 
}
```

If you want to remove the checked items from `listView1` you can try this:

```
for(int i = listView1.Items.Count-1; i >= 0; i--){
   var item = listView1.Items[i];
   if(item.Checked) {
      listView1.Items.Remove(item);
      listView2.Items.Add(item);
   }
}
```

If you want to add the checked item to `listView2` only when it is checked in the `listView1`, try this:

```
private void Listview1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Item.Checked){
      listView1.Items.Remove(e.Item);
      listView2.Items.Add(e.Item);      
    }
}
```

**Update**: To register the `Listview1_ItemChecked` handler for the `listView1.ItemChecked` event, try this code (placed in your form constructor):

```
public Form1(){  
  InitializeComponent();
  listView1.ItemChecked += Listview1_ItemChecked;
}
```

Comment: I am trying the if(e.item.checked) coz looks like what I want to do... yet Its not working. I have both listviews on the same form. I dont see the items passing... I wonder what I am doing wrong... I hope Im not been blond here...

Comment: @user3012159 I provided 3 code snippets, could you tell me which one is not working? I hope there is not any exception.

Comment: I am using the last snippet, the code looks right.. yet when I add breakpoints on the code and debug, its like to app doesnt even look at that snippet when been checked. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @user3012159 do you know how to register the `Listview1_ItemChecked` event handler for the `Listview1.ItemChecked` event? What you described means that that event handler is not registered/attached correctly.

Comment: Please can you give me a basic guideline on how to do this ?

Comment: @user3012159 see the update to know how, you should learn more about **event** in C# as well as `winforms` first, it would help you better.

Comment: Thank you, its working, I had to edit the code as I dont want to remove the item from the first list. Had to use the clone method. Thank you once again. @king king

Answer (score 0):

you can try in LINQ

```
var checkedItems = (from ListViewItem item in listView1.Items select item != null &&  item.Checked == true).ToList();
listview2.DataSource = checkedItems; //if using data basic asp.net data bind
listview2.DataBind();
```